# Triviality of a bundle given that the corresponding bundle of covering spaces is trivial

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

Let $F,\ E,\ B$ be connected manifolds and  $$F\hookrightarrow E\to B$$ be a fiber bundle. Suppose that $F$ is simply-connected and that $\pi_1(E)=\pi_1(B)= \mathbb Z_2$.

Now consider the universal covering manifolds $\tilde E$ and  $\tilde B$ of $E$ and $B$ respectively. Suppose that we have the following fiber bundle 
$$F\hookrightarrow \tilde E\to \tilde B$$
and given that this bundle is trivial i.e. $\tilde E=F\times \tilde B$. Does this imply that also $E=F\times B$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  For instance, let $B=\mathbb{R}P^2$ and let $E$ be the $S^2$-bundle on $B$ classified by the map $B\to \mathbb{R}P^\infty=B\mathbb{Z}_2\to BO(3)$ where the first map is the inclusion and the second map is induced by the map $\mathbb{Z}/2\to O(3)$ sending a generator to $-I$.  This $S^2$-bundle is nontrivial since it is not orientable: going around a loop that generates $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2)$, the orientation on the fiber gets reversed since $-I$ is orientation-reversing.  Since $F=S^2$ is simply connected, the long exact sequence on homotopy groups immediately implies $\pi_1(E)\cong\pi_1(B)\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$.

On the other hand, the universal cover bundle $\tilde{E}$ on $\tilde{B}$ is the bundle classified by the composition $\tilde{B}\to B\to B\mathbb{Z}_2\to BO(3)$.  But since $\tilde{B}$ is simply connected, the composition $\tilde{B}\to B\to B\mathbb{Z}_2$ is already nullhomotopic, and thus the classifying map of the bundle $\tilde{E}$ is nullhomotopic so it is a trivial bundle.

Comment: I don't understand what is $\mathbb RP^\infty=B\mathbb Z_2$?

Comment: The infinite-dimensional real projective space, which is also the classifying space for $\mathbb{Z}_2$-bundles.  Another way to say this is that we are taking the orientation $\mathbb{Z}_2$-bundle on $\mathbb{R}P^2$ and then taking the associated $S^2$-bundle by letting $\mathbb{Z}_2$ act on $S^2$ by the antipodal map.

Comment: The universal cover bundle then has the same description (take the orientation bundle and then the associated $S^2$-bundle), but the orientation bundle on $\tilde{B}$ is now trivial and thus so is the associated bundle.

Comment: Ok I see, very nice, thanks! This gives rise to a question now: If the all spaces in question are orientate,  do you think the statement then is true?

Comment: You could do the same thing with $\mathbb{R}P^3$ instead of $\mathbb{R}P^2$, and with an $S^2\times S^2$-bundle where $\mathbb{Z}_2$ acts on $S^2\times S^2$ by swapping the coordinates (which is orientation-preserving, so that $E$ will be orientable).  The fact that $E$ is a nontrivial bundle follows from the fact that the coordinate-swapping map on $S^2\times S^2$ is not isotopic to the identity.

Comment: Thank you very much!